# Is my dataset a time series dataset? and should I use an LSTM

Tags: time-series, lstm

I have a dataset where I am recording temperature after every 4milliseconds till 500 and another feature 'conductivity value'. The length of the dataset is around a 1000 rows.
I need to find the conductivity value based on the temperature pattern.

t1 t2 t3....t5 | conductivityvalue

90 91 93....96 | 0.34

I am bit confused on how to use the dataset in a time series model such as LSTM because I have all the time sequence in columns and I don't know the conductivity values in between as in t2,t3,t4.

Can you guys help me out?